# In Laravel, do I have to create a separate model and controller for each database table/collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a little application with PHP web framework Laravel v6 and MongoDB (with [jenssegers moloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)) as database engine. This is my first encounter with any MVC framework. I have the following collections in my database:

1. allPaintingsCollection
2. paintingHistoriesCollection
3. paintingCategoriesCollection
4. artGalleriesCollection
5. paintingArtistsCollection
6. supervisorArtistsCollection
7. smPlatformsCollection
8. nonSmPlatformsCollection
9. targetSchoolsCollection

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q). I have the following two questions:

1. Do I have to create a separate Model (separate class in a separate file) for each collection above?
2. Do I have to create a separate Controller (separate class in a separate file) for each collection above?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a `Mongo` Collection is, but if it's anything like a standard database table, then yes, you should have a Model for each one. If they have similar functionality, then you can extend a parent model off of `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`, then extend all your `Collection` models off of that. As for Controllers, you don't _need_ to have a Controller for each Model, but it's generally a good idea to have multiple Controllers. It might make sense to have a Controller handle multiple models, but it's not required to be 1-to-1.

Answer (score 1):

New Answer:
1. Yes, you will need to create a separate model to use the ORM. Ideally, the model should only support a single collection, doing so you can create custom logic. Remember, One Model One Collection/Table.

2. For Controllers, you can write it any way you like, you can use all models inside a single controller. But what I have learned so far using Laravel, you should create a single controller for each model to fully and logically support the separation of concerns.

**Know the BTS:**

Laravel heavily uses PHP Composer's autoloader functionality, so having multiple classes in a single file won't work.

For example, when autoloader starts, it would look for **User** class in \App\Models\User.php file. Having multiple classes in a single file won't help in this case.

Latest Laravel's version follow [PSR-4 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). You can have a look at it for more understanding.

For more PHP coding standards you can have a look at [PSR-2 standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Comment: I think your answer is irrelevant to the question. The OP never mention anything about having multiple class in a single file. In fact, he knows that he would have to create the model and controller in a separate class and file.

Comment: Thanks for the point mate, I have added the thought process and reasoning behind it also. Let me know if it helpful now.