# In Laravel, how to select data from multiple db tables in my view file?

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a little application with PHP web framework Laravel v6 and MongoDB (with jenssegers moloquent) as database engine.

Disclaimer: This is my first encounter with any MVC framework.

I have 9 tables ('collections' in Mongodb but I am calling it 'tables' for generalization/simplicity) in my database and I need to select a lot of data from 8 of them in a single view.

So I reckon that it won't be a good idea to pass such long, multiple JSON strings to the view from the controller which calls the view?

**So what would be the way to select data from multiple tables in my `blade.php` file?**

If it was one table, then may be we could do something like `App\ModelForThatTable::all();` but I need to select from multiple different tables in my view file. So how do I do that?

Comment: You'd still do all the querying in the controller, but you wouldn't pass as `JSON`. The syntax for returning data to a view is `return view('viewname', ['data' => $data]);` (or `compact('data')`), or `view()->with(['data' => $data]);`, etc etc. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views for full details.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you very much. Even if we are passing an array, passing around a big chunk of data (say 10k records from db) doesn't feel right/intuitive. So far in MVC, I am feeling that too many files are created (for separate models etc), and too much overhead to achieve very simple things.

Comment: Fair enough. It sounds like you need to separate your functionality a little better; passing that much data to a single view is going to be taxing, no matter how you look at it. Are you able to separate your logic into different routes/controllers/views? Having a "dashboard" where you display a lot of information is good, but it's generally summarized in the Controller before display, then you have dedicated routes/controllers/view (MVC, with Create Read Update Delete operations) for each Model, etc etc.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I am not fully clear what exactly you mean after "Are you able to separate your logic...". I have the db tables mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437927/in-laravel-do-i-have-to-create-a-separate-model-and-controller-for-each-databas). In my dashboard, I need to show all records from `allPaintingsCollection` in the form of a table, and data from almost all other tables is needed to display values in individual entries of the table correctly. So I really need to display all of this data in a table in my dashboard.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying; the data is all connected; gotcha. All I meant was having a section of your app for "Paintings", and another for "Galleries", etc etc. To address displaying all of your paintings in a table, with their related Gallery, History, etc, that's where Relationships come in. In the Controller, you'd do `Painting::with(['gallery', 'history'])->get();`, then `return view('paintings.index')->with(['paintings' => $paintings]);`, then display them in a Table. I think you question might be a bit too broad to answer though; I'd need to see you models/relationships etc...

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I'll look into "Laravel Relationships"

Comment: No problem! Here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can select all data from one controller. Just import all of the models you have and select data from their table, then return it from the controller to the view.